# Django - create a foreign key with boolean

Tags: python, django, web, model

I have some questions on my site and I want them to be seen only by users that I want. I created a profile class and for each profile I want to create a boolean Field for each question. For the moment my code looks like this :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   accessquestion1 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   accessquestion2 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   accessquestion3 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Can I optimize this code with a kind of 'boolean foreign key' ??

Comment: What exactly do you want to optimize: number of fields, number of code lines, performance or something else? If performance, then what operations (queries) do you consider?

Answer (score 0):

If I am following you correctly you want to create a foreignkey to add more questions to the profile. If this is the case then I would set it up like this.

```
class ProfileQuestions(models.Model):
    question = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questions = models.ForeignKey(ProfileQuestions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using PostgreSQL as your backend, you could consider

1. using an JSON field :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

create it like so (not tested):

```
Profile.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={'question1': True})
Profile.objects.create(name='Meg', data={'question2': False})

Profile.objects.filter(data__question1=True)
<QuerySet [<Profile: Rufus>]>
```

2. an Array

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

and have each index be either 0 for False, or 1 for True.. So if your app has 100 questions, each user would have an array of size 100.